# VPS crashes when connecting to OpenVPN server

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

Basically, I have a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04, and I am trying to make it connect to an OpenVPN server, however, when it connects, I lose connection to the server and have to restart it before I can connect again.
Here is the VPN config

Client

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote ***.***.***.*** 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Server

```
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Comment: Nothing suspicious there. Please provide the server configuration as well, including matching files from the client config folder, if any.

Comment: Edited in the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

do you need your outgoing traffic flow onto the vpn server? if no remove the 
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

and try again

do you have ssh access to the openvpn server? if yes try to log in to the client from the vpn server to the ip of the client's PP (10.8.0.x)

it seems like you have a routing problem after vpn connection